# Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration' but it exists

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my configuration:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-5.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>

    <mapping class="Mapping.AccountMap"
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I read that i should change the "Doctype" and i did from other answers i have found, yet this error occurs:

Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 8 and column 63 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.

Comment: For me this error occurred when I tried to read a `hibernate-configuration` file when a `hibernate-mapping` file was wanted. For example in SpringBoot's `builder.mappingResource("Entity.hbm.xml", "AnotherEntity.hbm.xml")`.

Answer (score 3):

Your dtd url is false ... seems like hibernate-configuration-5.0.dtd doesn't exist ... use this :

```
http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd
```

change the whole header :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-5.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

**TO**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration
        PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Still: Cannot find the declaration of element

Comment: with the second i get: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null

Comment: I download new config from hibernate.org still: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this header block. It works for me and also check parse error in your XML file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

---

Here i am posting some sample xml file may be it will help you.

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="org.java.dto.UserDetails"/>


</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```